# Checking if date is within a date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have a GridView and I want to change the colour of the row if the date in a column is within a certain date range.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParse(c.Text, out dt))
{
    if (dt.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(Mod.ValidUntilDays).Date && dt.Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(Mod.ValidUntilDays).Date)
     {
         e.Item.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0303");
     }
}
```

So the value coming from the grid is `dt.Date` is equal to `23/09/2016 00:00:00` and the date range I want to check is `25/09/2016 00:00:00`. `Mod.ValidUntilDays` just adds 5 days to Today's date.

So what I am trying to do is check is`23/09/2016 00:00:00` within the 5 day range which it is but the code never goes into the if statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are asking the date to be >= 5-days-time and <= 5-days-time. So unless it == 5-days-time it'll return false. I think you mean this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParse(c.Text, out dt))
{
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  if (dt.Date >= now.Date && dt.Date <= now.AddDays(Mod.ValidUntilDays).Date)
  {
     e.Item.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0303");
  }
}
```